# Why do I get permission denied on constructing URL in Edge?

Tags: javascript, node.js, urlparse

I am having the following line on console on chrome:
`new URL('http:www.yahoo.com')`

and I get the correct object:

```
    URL {href: "http://www.yahoo.com/", origin: "http://www.yahoo.com", protocol: "http:", username: "", password: "", …} hash: "" host: "www.yahoo.com" hostname: "www.yahoo.com" href: "http://www.yahoo.com/" origin: "http://www.yahoo.com" password: "" pathname: "/" port: "" protocol: "http:" search: "" searchParams: URLSearchParams {} username: ""
```

but as I try the exact same line on Edge browser, I get the following:

```
    ``[object URL]: {hash: "", host: "", hostname: "", href: <Permission denied>: , origin: "http://"...}
    hash: ""
    host: ""
    hostname: ""
    href: <Permission denied>
    origin: "http://"
    password: ""
    pathname: "www.yahoo.com"
    port: ""
    protocol: "http:"
    search: ""

    searchParams: Object
    username: ""
    username: ""``
```

Shouldn't URL constructor be supported the same in Edge as well according to this [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)?

Comment: It is. And as soon as you feed an actual URL to it, it works as advertised. The double backslashes after `protocol:` aren’t optional.

Comment: Isn't strange that in Chrome it works fine without those backslashes?

Comment: No, strange is only to draw such conclusions from the extended error tolerance a specific implementation might show ;-)

Comment: alright ... :) I was using this for the rest of the protocols too such as mailto in which we don't need the backslashes but I guess now I will have to change the code and  not rely on the error tolerance of the library to be the same in all supported browsers.

Comment: Thanks @misorude!